# How to reload Angular page so that session variable are updated?

Tags: angular

So I have created a login system (Django and Angular) and have restricted users from accessing all routes unless they are logged in. The app works as expected, but has a glitch- I have to reload manually for session variable to get updated (confirmed through console.log()).

The menu is simple:

```html
<div class="alert alert-warning full-height">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" [routerLink]="['/login']">Login</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" [routerLink]="['/home']">Home</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" [routerLink]="['/department-list']">Department List</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" [routerLink]="['/logout']">Logout</button>
</div>
```

Here is app.module.ts:

```html
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { NgxPaginationModule } from 'ngx-pagination';  // npm i ngx-pagination

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './components/header/header.component';
import { SidebarComponent } from './components/sidebar/sidebar.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';

import { DepartmentListComponent } from './components/department-list/department-list.component';

import { LoginComponent } from './auth-component/login/login.component';
import { LogoutComponent } from './auth-component/logout/logout.component';

const routes = [
  {path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'home'},
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: 'logout', component: LogoutComponent},
  {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
  {path: 'department-list', component: DepartmentListComponent},
  {path: '**', redirectTo: 'home'},
]
and so on.....
```

My login page is basic and login.component.ts looks like:

```html
import { LoginService } from './../../service/login.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Login } from './../../model/login';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  login: Login;

  constructor(private service: LoginService,
    private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.login = new Login();
  }

  sendLoginCredentials(){
    this.service.authorizeUser(this.login)
    .subscribe((data)=>{
      this.login.auth_token = data.auth_token;
      sessionStorage.setItem('AuthToken', this.login.auth_token);
      this.router.navigate(['/home']);
    })
  }


}
```

Login.service.ts:

```html
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Login } from './../model/login';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

const URL = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/token/";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class UserService {

  public login: Login = new Login();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  authorizeUser(login: Login): Observable<Login> {
    return this.http.post(URL + 'login/', login)
    .map(data => data as Login);
  }
  }
```

Department.service.ts:

```html
import { Login } from './../model/login';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Department } from '../model/department';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'; // npm install rxjs-compat

const URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/';
let authValue = sessionStorage.getItem('AuthToken');
let httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  Authorization: 'token ' + authValue,
});

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class DepartmentService {

  login: Login = new Login();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getAllDepartments(): Observable<Department[]> {
    return this.http
      .get(URL + 'department-list/', { headers: httpHeaders })
      .map((resp) => resp as Department[]);
  }
}
```

logout.service.ts:

```html
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Login } from '../model/login';

let authValue = sessionStorage.getItem("AuthToken");
console.log(authValue);
let httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  Authorization: 'token ' + authValue,
});

const URL = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/token/";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LogoutService {

  login: Login = new Login();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  logoutUser(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(URL + 'logout/', JSON.stringify(this.login.auth_token), {headers: httpHeaders});
  }

}
```

Similarly, my logout page is very basic and logout.component.ts looks like:

```html
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { LogoutService } from 'src/app/service/logout.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-logout',
  templateUrl: './logout.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./logout.component.css']
})
export class LogoutComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private service: LogoutService,
    private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  logoutUser(){
    this.service.logoutUser()
    .subscribe(()=>{
      sessionStorage.removeItem('AuthToken');
      this.router.navigate(['/home']);
    });
  }

}
```

Unless I refresh, the AuthToken is always null. I am relatively new to Angular, so any help is appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried running window.location.reload();

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It works but I want the app to render another component, and the reload takes it back to the previous component. I was looking to see if there was an "angular way" to solve it. If I can't find/understand any, i'll work with this.

Answer (score 0):

It's null/undefined without a reload because you read the AuthToken from the SessionStorage only once, when your application is initialized (note that all services are provided in 'root', meaning the top level depencency injector, which happens on application bootstrap).

You need to update the AuthToken when the user logs in or out, not when loading the application. Consider a more centralized approach (e.g. replacing `login` and `logout` with a combined `user` service). That new service could then have a variable with the `AuthToken` which it will update on logout and login (while also updating the `SessionStorage`). Everybody else will then need to reference that property.